# secure a layer in geoserver with password using OpenLayers

Tags: authentication, openlayers, geoserver

Is there a possibility to give geoserver-layers a login/password to make them visible or invisible? I have a simple web service with geoserver layers using OpenLayers but these layers contain sensitive data so they have to be behind some authentication to be seen. As I'm a simple programmer, I would like a layer authentication instead of generating a login system of my web service.

I saw some information online but in geoserver I only saw how to enable a layer, not how to secure a layer with a password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) provides a detailed and very flexible [authentication](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/index.html) mechanism. It can be hooked in to your existing [LDAP system](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#ldap-authentication) or run entirely [locally with a simple file](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#username-password-authentication) lookup or a [JDBC database](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#jdbc-authentication).

Once you have decided how to authenticate your users you can then set security rules for [individual users or groups](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/usergrouprole/index.html) of users for the entire service or [workspaces and individual layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html).

So in your case I suspect you need to set up users' login using whichever system you prefer and then set a series of rules for the different layers. I would advise working through one of the [tutorials](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/index.html) before you try it with a real system.